# Unwinding through multiple views using a custom segue in iOS8 causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a storyboard-based app, for which I have created custom segues, which use a custom animation controller that I have created.

Everything works fine when segueing forward/unwinding back one screen at a time. However, when I try to unwind through a stack of screens (e.g. I had segued First->Second->Third and then try to unwind back Third->First), I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1)` error.

The Apple documentation for UIViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) says that

> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

So as I understand this, if I call ‘dismissViewControllerAnimated’ on First, it should dismiss Third using its modal transition style, and just remove Second from the stack.

Therefore my UnwindSegue.perform method is:

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    sourceViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    sourceViewController.transitioningDelegate = self;

    [destinationViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //Error occurs here
}
```

The last line crashes with the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

I’ve done some digging around (by enabling zombies), and it seems like UIViewController internally has a weak reference to my ‘forward’ segue - 
`FirstController.dismissViewControllerAnimated` calls `UIViewController._customAnimatorForDismissedController`, which calls methods on the segue Second->Third (which no longer exists).

Anyone got any idea on whether this behaviour is expected, or where I'm going wrong? Everything works in iOS7.

ETA: Crash log

```
Incident Identifier: 821DC9AC-E1A1-4CCD-8A3F-718577C1634D
CrashReporter Key:   35442db1a2bdce63197d4abe696619ca29fe9675
Hardware Model:      iPad4,1
Process:             TestProject [3792]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B56179DF-3A3D-4C57-A5A0-910EF0BAEB8D/TestProject.app/TestProject
Identifier:          com.xyz.TestProject
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-02-10 17:32:35.524 +0000
Launch Time:         2015-02-10 17:32:15.301 +0000
OS Version:          iOS 8.1.2 (12B440)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000554fbeb8
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000197cd7bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x000000018bb83c3c -[UIViewController _customAnimatorForDismissedController:] + 80
2   UIKit                           0x000000018bb83a84 -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] + 620
3   UIKit                           0x000000018bb2c074 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 948
4   UIKit                           0x000000018bb2bc5c -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:] + 248
5   TestProject                     0x00000001000cd768 -[XYZUnwindStoryboardSegue perform] (XYZUnwindStoryboardSegue.m:26)
6   UIKit                           0x000000018ba90d30 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
7   UIKit                           0x000000018ba79e44 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 608
8   UIKit                           0x000000018ba906cc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 588
9   UIKit                           0x000000018ba90358 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 696
10  UIKit                           0x000000018ba898ac -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 680
11  UIKit                           0x000000018ba5cfa4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 260
12  UIKit                           0x000000018bcfbf54 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14988
13  UIKit                           0x000000018ba5b50c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1612
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001872629e8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187261c8c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 260
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018725fd3c __CFRunLoopRun + 708
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018718d0a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
18  GraphicsServices                0x00000001902f35a0 GSEventRunModal + 164
19  UIKit                           0x000000018bac23bc UIApplicationMain + 1484
20  TestProject                     0x00000001000ce7ec main (main.m:14)
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000198332a04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198430c94 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100141254 0x100130000 + 70228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100132ef4 0x100130000 + 12020

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019844bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001984e5390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001984e4fa4 start_wqthread + 0
```

Comment: Please post the crash log, thanks.

Comment: I suspect the problem lies in your custom animation transition, you might want to set breakpoints in there and try to figure out at what point your code is crashing, perhaps you are referencing a property that no longer exists in memory. I suggest you also post that custom transition code here if you still need help debugging.